# macOS Mojave launchd regular interval script - error is always "Found non-key inside <dict> at line 11"

Tags: macos, mojave, launchd

The .plist in question is at the bottom but I can't find a way to run it every 7200 seconds.  Checking it produces the same error.

I have tried various versions taken from the StackExchange such as:

```
 <key>StartInterval</key>
 <integer>5</integer>
 <key>ThrottleInterval</key>
 <integer>0</integer>
 <true/>
```

The rest of it is fine as proved by removing the interval arguments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>Label</key>
 <string>Wi-Fi.OFF.ON</string>
 <key>Program</key>
 <string>/Users/XXXXX/Desktop/Wi-Fi.OFF.then.ON.sh</string>
 <key>StartInterval</key>
 <integer>7200</integer>
 <true/>
</dict>
</plist>

plutil -lint TEST

TEST: Found non-key inside <dict> at line 11
```

Can anyone point out my error in Mojave?

Comment: Why do you have a "true" key in the Interval?  Did you remove some other key like `RunAtLoad`?  Remove it and see if it works.

Comment: @Allan - Yes, that worked.  I took the code from an example as I'm learning this and python from scratch.  Thanks.